# Javascript: Implementing shortcut keys

Tags: javascript, html, keyboard-shortcuts

I am quite new to javascript, but not to programing in general. What I attempt to do is have the page wait for the user to use a keyboard shortcut, and then proceed to open a popup. A few hours with confusing tutorials leads me to nothing. I'll re-iterate, this is **not asp** or other such scripts, this is **javascript** that it should be written in.

I wish online code example would provide a full, working, ready-to-run source code file from which I can learn more from by looking at instead of text explanations and code snippets.

Keeping in mind my noobishness to this, could you explain what and how this would be done, or better yet, instead give the simplest possible working HTML+js example - a blank page that gives a popup when <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> is hit for instance. The latter would be far more effective (and probably easier for you than typing out a description) in me figuring this out.

**NOTE:** Im not trying to do anything complicated, just the basics

Comment: Please take some time to read through the [faq]. You'll need to ask a real question about some real code that you've written if you want us to be able to help you.

Comment: I did as you said and this question is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Don't steal my code and put it as part of your question just to make it "acceptable", kthx

Comment: First of all the <script></script> section should be in the <head> section. But the answer from @Kolink doesnt work out of the box. Some keys are actually not allowed to be over-ridden by certain browsers for security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with:

```
window.onkeydown = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var k = e.keyCode || e.which;
    switch(k) {
        case ...:
            // do something
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now add some `case`s. For example, to capture a space you would use `case 32`.

You can also combine with modifier keys. For example, to capture Ctrl+Space:

```
case 32:
    if( e.ctrlKey) {
        // do something
        return false;
    }
    return true;
```

Keep adding shortcuts in this way, just be careful not to interfere too much with expected behaviour.

Comment: I edited the question and added my resultant html/js code that does not work. Maybe im just dumb but it does not work as it should.

Comment: Are you testing by pressing Ctrl+Space?

Comment: Ah. Thats the problem, was using only space. I apologize, iv been messing around with various js features for some 12 hours and my brain is doing loops and backflips >.< Thank you very much.